# pyspark if statement optimization

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hello guys I'm doing a dataframe filtering based on if condition but the problem that I must repeat the same code 3 times in every if condition and I don't want to do that. It's not optimized.
Someone has any idea how to optimize that?
here is the code exemple

```
if sexe == "male":

    new_df = (
        df.where(F.col("sexe") == 1)
        .where(F.col("column_flag") == False)
        .withColumn("new_column", F.col("column1") / F.col("column3"))
    )

elif sexe == "female":
    new_df = (
        df.where(F.col("sexe") == 2)
        .where(F.col("column_flag") == False)
        .withColumn("new_column", F.col("column1") / F.col("column3"))
    )
else:
    new_df = df.where(F.col("column_flag") == False).withColumn(
        "new_column", F.col("column1") / F.col("column3")
    )
```

Comment: are you asking for a more efficient method or simply a way to avoid duplicate code?

Comment: just a simply a way to avoid duplicate code but if you have any suggestion I'll take it, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One way is to build the filtering expression then use it to filter the dataframe:

```py
filter_expr = ~F.col("column_flag")

if sexe == "male":
    filter_expr = filter_expr & F.col("sexe") == 1
elif sexe == "female":
    filter_expr = filter_expr & F.col("sexe") == 2

new_df = df.filter(filter_expr).withColumn(
    "new_column", F.col("column1") / F.col("column3")
)
```